# :dependent => :delete on belongs_to doesn't delete owner object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have been checking options of [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) method and testing following behavior in Rails 3.2.7

As per above link the `:dependent` option states that

> If set to :destroy, the associated object is destroyed when this
>   object is. If set to :delete, the associated object is deleted without
>   calling its destroy method.

As I understand the Author should be removed if Post is removed in following case:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :dependent => :delete
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_one :post

  before_destroy :log_author_removal

  private
    def log_author_removal
      logger.error('Author is getting removed')
    end

end
```

In console:

```
> Post.first
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" LIMIT 1
 => #<Post id: 5, title: "Post 5", author_id: 3>
> p.delete
  SQL (197.7ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 5
 => #<Post id: 5, title: "Post 5", author_id: 3> 
> Author.find(3)
  Author Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 => #<Author id: 3, name: "Author 3">
```

However calling `p.destroy` deletes associated author.

Am I misunderstood above quoted statement?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, calling `delete` generally skips all callbacks that either you or rails set on destroying the record. These include callbacks like `before_destroy` and also destroying associated records.

Therefore if you call `p.delete` it will not do anything with the associated records.

When you call `p.destroy` it will:

1. Call the `before_destroy` callback if set.
2. Delete the object.
3. If you set `:dependent => :delete`, it will simply delete the Author object. If you set it to `:destroy` it will repeat this whole process for the author object (callback & destroying its related records if applicable).
4. Call the `after_destroy` callback if set.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. As per point 3, the author object should be deleted but actually it is not. That is why I posted here to get inputs from community

Comment: @AmitPatel Yes but you didn't call `destroy`, you called `delete`.

Comment: That means `delete` would not have any impact on associated object irrespective of what is set for `:dependent`.

Answer (score 7):

From what I understand :

`:dependent => :destroy` will trigger `association.destroy` if you call `destroy` on the object.

`:dependent => :delete` will trigger `association.delete` if you call `destroy` on the object.

In both cases, you have to call `destroy` on the parent object. The difference lies in th methos that is called on the child object. If you don't want to trigger destroy filters on the child object use `:dependent => :delete`. If you do want them, use `:dependent => :destroy`.

By quickly taking a look at the source here : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/357e288f4470f484ecd500954fd17fba2512c416/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb#L68

We see that calling dependent will just create an after_destroy on the parent model, calling either `delete` or `destroy` on the child object. But in both cases, it creates an `after_destroy`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

belongs_to association support both **:delete** and **:destroy** for **:dependent**.
you can refer below link
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

calling delete skips all callbacks like before_destroy and as well won't delete associated records for association object as well.

Example

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :project, :dependent => :delete
has_many :resources, :dependent => :delete
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order, :dependent => :delete
end
```

In above code,if project has been destroyed then order will as well deleted but resources in order won't delete
but if we use

```
belongs_to :order, :dependent => :destroy
```

then resources attached with orders as well deleted on project destroy.

Answer (score 1):

```
 belongs_to :author, :dependent => :delete
```

Should be: 
     belongs_to :author, :dependent => :destroy

:destroy and :delete behave differently in ActiveRecord, delete bypasses validations and AR associations, thus associated objects are not being removed.

Comment: Should one use delete or destroy is different thing. I just want to understand if associated record should be deleted or not as per the statement _If set to :delete, the associated object is deleted without calling its destroy method_

Answer (score -1):

belongs_to association can't support the **:delete** for **:depedent**. It supports only **:destroy**. Please refer this link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: I could not find anything that states belongs_to association can't support the :delete for : dependent.